# How to make Wagtail search case-insensitive

Tags: python, django, search, elasticsearch, wagtail

I use Wagtail serach:

```
query = self.request.query_params
questions = models.Questions.objects.filter(
    answer__isnull=False,
    owner__isnull=False).exclude(answer__exact='')
s = get_search_backend()
results = s.search(query[u'question'], questions)
```

And this is how I set up the indexing of my `Questions` model:

```
search_fields = [
    index.SearchField('question', partial_match=True, boost=2),
    index.FilterField('answer'),
    index.FilterField('owner_id')
]
```

But it case sensitive. So queries `how` and `How` will give different results.

I need to make my search behave this way:

When I type either `how` or `How`, it should return

```
how to...
How to...
The way how...
THE WAY HoW...
```

In other words, it should find all mentions of `how` in all posible cases.

How do I make it work?

P.S.: I'm using default backend, and I'm free to change it if needed.

Comment: Can you share how you have set up the indexing of your `Questions` model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Wagtail's elasticsearch backend, fields indexed with `partial_match=True` are tokenized in [lowercase](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/blob/v1.5.3/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py#L623). So to accomplish case-insensitive search all you need to do is lowercase the query string:

```
results = s.search(query[u'question'].lower(), questions)
```

Comment: Then questions that start from uppercase letter will not be found

Comment: Is there a way to turn on case-insensitive search in the settings.py file ? Maybe with something like: WAGTAIL_SEARCH_CASE_INSENSITIVE = True